NextJS 14 and MUI 6 dynamic theme switcher
Hey i've been struggling for hours for something that seams simple as first glance. Idea is simple i have Theme with dark and light pallete and i want to switch between them using the  useColorScheme hook.
my client Provider:
'use client';

import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider, useColorScheme } from '@mui/material';
import theme from '@/styles/theme';
import { ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function ClientThemeProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const { mode, setMode } = useColorScheme(); // useColorScheme to manage theme

  // Set the theme mode based on the stored value or default to dark
  useEffect(() => {
    const storedMode = localStorage.getItem('mui-mode');
    if (!storedMode) {
      setMode('dark'); // Set dark mode as default
    } else {
      setMode(storedMode as 'light' | 'dark'); // Set stored mode (light or dark)
    }
  }, [setMode]);

  // Save the mode in localStorage every time it changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (mode) {
      localStorage.setItem('mui-mode', mode);
    }
  }, [mode]);

  // Dynamically apply the theme based on the current mode
  const appliedTheme = { ...theme, palette: { mode } };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={appliedTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}


my theme:
'use client';

import { extendTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Roboto } from 'next/font/google';

// Load Roboto font from Google Fonts
const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: ['300', '400', '500', '700'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
});

// Create the extended theme with color schemes (light and dark)
const theme = extendTheme({
  cssVarPrefix: 'mui', // Enable CSS variables
  typography: {
    fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
  },
  colorSchemes: {
    light: {
      palette: {
        mode: 'light',
        background: {
          default: '#f5f5f5', // Light mode background color
          paper: '#ffffff',
        },
        text: {
          primary: '#000000',
        },
      },
    },
    dark: {
      palette: {
        mode: 'dark',
        background: {
          default: '#121212', // Dark mode background color
          paper: '#1e1e1e',
        },
        text: {
          primary: '#ffffff',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;


my root layout:
 <body>
        <ClientThemeProvider>
          <AppRouterCacheProvider>
            <UserProvider token={tokens?.decodedToken}>
              <Box
                sx={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  width: '100%',
                  height: '98%',
                  marginTop: '10px',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
              >
                {/* {tokens?.decodedToken && <Navigation />} */}
                <Box style={{ width: tokens?.decodedToken ? '70%' : '100%' }}>{children}</Box>
              </Box>
            </UserProvider>
          </AppRouterCacheProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>

and then i have in some client component something like this:
      setMode(mode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'); // Toggle between light and dark

nothing is changing i always start on darkmode for whatever reason and it never changes
